# Table of contents not appearing on R-Markdown html file?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to create a HTML file with a TOC for my graphs and tables, but it's not appearing when I knit it.

This is my code:

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
h1, h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

---
title: |
  ![](https://sigaenf.subpav.org/sites/default/files/inline-images/Logo_SMS_2022b.png){width=400px style="display: block; margin:0 auto;"}
  **NVH**
author: "CADV"
date: Base do dia **29/09/2023**
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: TRUE
    toc_float: TRUE
---
````

I don't know if it's something to do with the image position.

I'm also using this code for a plot.

````
## Indicadores { .tabset .tabset-pills}

### Sexo


```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

sexo <- dados %>%
  group_by(sexo, anoobito) %>%
  tally %>%
  filter(sexo != "IGNORADO") %>%
  mutate(anoobito = as.character(anoobito)) %>%
  rename("Sexo" = "sexo")


p <- ggplot(sexo, aes(x = anoobito, y = n, group = Sexo)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Sexo), size = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Sexo), size = 3) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 15) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1200), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black"), axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black")) +  #coloco a fonte dos eixos de preto e giro o eixo x em 90 graus
  labs(
    x = "Ano do Óbito", # label do eixo X
    y = "Número de Óbitos") 

ggplotly(p)
````

Does { .tabset .tabset-pills} make any difference on a floating toc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be caused by including the CSS chunk ahead of the document YAML.  I put the CSS code into a file `test.css` in the same directory as the document, i.e. just these lines:

```css
h1, h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

An even simpler solution is to just move the CSS below the header:

````
---
title: |
  ![](https://sigaenf.subpav.org/sites/default/files/inline-images/Logo_SMS_2022b.png){width=400px style="display: block; margin:0 auto;"}
  **NVH**
author: "CADV"
date: Base do dia **29/09/2023**
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: TRUE
    toc_float: TRUE
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
h1, h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

# Main 1

## Sub 1

## Sub 2

# Main 2
````